# How to open direct list view instead of select "Search More.." in Many2one field for Odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10, many-to-one

I have a Many2one field and when we selecting "Search More.." then list view open for this field. Is this possible to open direct list view for this Many2one field instead of choosing "Search More.."?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please share your attempts, inputs.

Comment: I guess this is not going be the odoo way. so it is not easily possible

Comment: Hi, "Search More" feature was developed to speed up user experience as Many2one data may increase over the time. However, if you want to show all record in many2one you should use `widget="selection"`, but you can not create new record from that field.